# Suitable MOSFET for my application

Tags: mosfet, stm32

I need to control 12 small 12V vacuum pumps with 3.3V coming from a STM32 microcontroller. Those vacuum pumps don't draw more than ~1.5A.
My idea is to use MOSFETs but I'm having a hard time choosing. I have very limited space on my PCB.

What is the smallest MOSFET I can get?

I found this one [IRLR8726TRPBF](https://www.mouser.fr/datasheet/2/196/irlr8726pbf-1732973.pdf) and this one [IRLML6244TRPbF](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irlml6244pbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015356686fed261f) but I can't figure out if they are going to work.

Thanks for your help

Comment: My experience is that the connection terminal is bigger then the FETs Or how are you planning to connect all the wires?

Comment: @Oldfart I'm not quite sure I understand. I plan to connect my vacuum pumps to the PCB with Phoenix MC connectors. How does that affect the choice of the MOSFETs?

Comment: _"Those vacuum pumps don't draw more than ~1.5A"_ what is their startup current / DC resistance?

Comment: @BruceAbbott It is hard to find a datasheet of the vacuum pumps. The only thing I can give you is the Amazon link... https://www.amazon.com/Air-Pump-Electric-Treatment-Instrument/dp/B07FGFPKNS/ref=sr_1_13
I have no idea what the startup current/DC resistance of the motor is.